# In range v3 library, why ranges::copy do not work with output of ranges::views::chunk?

Tags: c++, c++20, range-v3

This works as expected:

```
#include <range/v3/all.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  auto chunklist = ranges::views::ints(1, 13) | ranges::views::chunk(4);
  for (auto rng : chunklist) {
    for (auto elt : rng)
      std::cout << elt << " ";    
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }
}
```

On the screen:

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 10 11 12
```

But if I try to substitute `ranges::copy` instead of for loop, I am getting compilation error

```
  auto chunklist = ranges::views::ints(1, 13) | ranges::views::chunk(4);
  for (auto rng : chunklist) {
    ranges::copy(rng, std::ostream_iterator<int>{std::cout, " "}); // FAIL
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }
```

Compilation error is rather obscure. I will not give full text here but looks like almost all concepts failed:

```
note:   constraints not satisfied
...
note: within '...' CPP_concept_bool weakly_incrementable =
...
note: within '...' CPP_concept_bool semiregular =
...
note: within '...' CPP_concept_bool default_constructible =
...
note: within '...' CPP_concept_bool constructible_from =
...
confused by earlier errors, bailing out
```

I am using gcc-9.3 with options:

```
g++ -fconcepts --std=c++2a chunksimplified.cc
```

And top of trunk range-v3 library from github

How shall I modify code in order to use explicit algorithm instead of raw loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is not with `ranges::copy`, it's just that `ranges::views` don't play nicely with `std::ostream_iterator`.

You can just use `ranges::ostream_iterator` instead:

```
ranges::copy(rng, ranges::ostream_iterator<int>{std::cout, " "});
```

Here's a working [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/HQJxaG).

Comment: Thanks it works. Didn't know about custom ostream_iterator in ranges namespace. Looks like C++20 only have std version.

Comment: Honestly, I haven't tried any of c++20 ranges stuff yet. Don't expect to be able to use *too many* ranges features in c++20. They'll get added, but it'll take time.